# Change autolayout contraints on uiview in a uiciollectionViewCell when orientation changes

Tags: uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a UICollectionView with a Custom UICollectionViewCell

The custom cell  has 1 cell per row in portrait and 2 cells per row across in landscape
Everything is using autolayout.

I have one a view in the cell which is constrained to be on the right edge of the cell.
When I change orientation to Landscape I set a different size of the cell so it is smaller (basically so i can view the 2 cells across)

I would like to hide the inner view on the right side of the cell in landscape instead of it just being resized to be smaller when the orientation changes

How do I do that ?